# Show data in GridView based on procedure by passing more the one parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure and I want to get the result in a `DataGridView`.

As shown below I have 5 parameters, and I want to use only one of them each time.  The rest can be null values.

For example:  "I want to filter by 5 different ways but, each time I will use one parameter only like ID, for second case I will filter by Date etc...."

I will pass the data from textboxes in the form.

I want the C# code or the way to do it directly from `GridView` through `SqlDataSource` :

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[ValidatiorSelection]
(
        @ID int
        ,@Cisco int
        ,@Date date
        ,@Resoution varchar(60)
        ,@Type varchar(30) 
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
           [Justification_ID]
          ,[Justification_Cisco]
          ,[HC_AgentName]
          ,[HC_Q]
          ,[HC_Cisco]
          ,[HC_Site]
          ,[HC_SPV]
          ,[HC_TeamLeader]
          ,[Justification_Date_Of_Case]
          ,[Justification_AgentShift]
          ,[Justification_From]
          ,[Justification_To]
          ,[Justification_OT_Duration]
          ,[Justification_Justification]
          ,[Justification_Description]
          ,[Justification_Creator]
          ,[Justification_Approved_By]
          ,[Justification_Type]
          ,[Justification_Group_ID]
          ,[WFM_Specialeist]
          ,[WFM_Resolution]
          ,[WFM_Status]
          ,[WFM_Comment]
          ,CASE WHEN DateDiff("d",[Justification_Date_Of_Case],[Justification_DT])>2 then 'Exceeded 48 Hours' 
           else 'During 48 Hours'
           end as 'Time Status'
          ,[Justification_DT] as 'Open Time'
          ,[WFM_DT] as 'Close Time'
    FROM 
        [ZainJTA].[dbo].[TBL_WFM] 
    RIGHT JOIN 
        ([ZainJTA].[dbo].[TBL_Justification] 
    LEFT JOIN 
        [ZainJTA].[dbo].[TBL_HC] ON [TBL_Justification].[Justification_Cisco] = [TBL_HC].[HC_Cisco]) ON [TBL_WFM].[WFM_JustificationID] = [TBL_Justification].[Justification_ID]
    WHERE
        [TBL_Justification].Justification_ID = @ID  
        OR [TBL_Justification].Justification_Cisco = @Cisco 
        OR [TBL_Justification].Justification_Date_Of_Case = @Date
        OR [TBL_Justification].Justification_Type = @Type
        OR [TBL_WFM].[WFM_Resolution] = @Resoution     
    ORDER BY 
        [Justification_ID] DESC
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource1"
 runat="server"
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"                
    SelectCommand="sp_lastnames">
     <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="Name" Type="String" ControlID="txtName" />
            </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: where shall i write this code ?
where shall i pass parameter

Comment: Paremeter names should be the name of ControlParameter and ControlID are the textboxes from where you want to get the values

Comment: i tried but doesn`t solve my problem , i want to pass one parameter and set the other by null value

Comment: Set DefaultValue attribute for the parameters so when you donot enter anything in txtboxes the default values will be passed to the stored procedure.

Comment: i tried to set it with "Null" it doesn`t work , if i set it with other value it will get wrong data

Comment: one more favor please, if i want to put validation group on the 5 Drop Lists to select one criteria only for search per time..... how shall i do that?

Comment: I think you can implement OnSelectedIndexChanged on the dropdowns so if the selected index of anyone of them changes the other should be set to default.